# Adding captions or descriptions to multiple image upload in Laravel

Tags: laravel, image, nested-loops, laravel-livewire, caption

So I am trying to upload images for a project where each image can have its own description or caption. I am trying to do this through the project creation form. Now, everything works except that I am getting duplicate entries in the project_images table because of the nested foreach loop, take a look at the summarised structure of the code Please, specifically the logic in the storProject method if anyone can help I will be forever grateful. Thank you.

I am using Laravel with Livewire.

Models

**Project Model**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('budget');
        $table->string('proposed_by');
        $table->string('executed_by');
        $table->string('status')->nullable();
        $table->integer('progress_indicator')->nullable();
        $table->date('starting_date');
        $table->date('completion_date')->nullable();
        $table->string('cover_image')->nullable();
        $table->mediumText('body')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Project_images Model**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('project_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('images');
        $table->string('caption')->nullable();
        $table->UnsignedBigInteger('project_id');
        $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**The Form**

```
<x-slot name="content">
        <x-errors />
        <div class="space-y-8 divide-y divide-gray-200  mt-10">

            <form method="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">


                    @if ($projectImages)
                        Images Preview:
                        <div class="flex flex-row m-8 ">

                            @foreach ($projectImages as $key => $projectImage)
                                <div class="flex flex-col gap-3">
                                    <img width="100%" src="{{ $projectImage->temporaryUrl() }}">
                                    <x-input placeholder="Caption"
                                        wire:model.defer="captions.{{ $key }}" />
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>

                <label class="inline-block mb-2 text-gray-500">Upload
                    Projects Images</label>
                <div class="flex items-center justify-center w-full">
                    <label
                        class="flex flex-col w-full h-32 border-2 border-dashed hover:bg-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300">
                        <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-7">
                            
                            <p class="pt-1 text-sm tracking-wider text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-600">
                                Select a photo</p>
                        </div>
                        <input wire:model="projectImages" type="file" multiple class="opacity-0" />
                    </label>
                </div>

                <x-textarea wire:model.lazy="body" label="Body" placeholder="write your article" />

            </form>

        </div>

    </x-slot>
    <x-slot name="footer">
        @if ($projectId)
            <div class="flex items-center gap-x-3 justify-end">
                <x-button wire:click="CancelConfirmation" label="Cancel" flat />
                <x-button type="submit" wire:click="updateProject" label="Update" wire:loading.attr="disabled"
                    primary />
            </div>
        @else
            <div class="flex items-center gap-x-3 justify-end">
                <x-button wire:click="CancelConfirmation" label="Cancel" flat />
                <x-button type="submit" wire:click="storeProject" label="Create" wire:loading.attr="disabled"
                    primary />
            </div>
        @endif

    </x-slot>

</x-jet-dialog-modal>
```

**The Project Component**

```
public function storeProject()
{
    $this->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required',
        'budget' => 'required',
        'proposedBy' => 'required',
        'executedBy' => 'required',
        'startingDate' => 'required',
        'completionDate' => 'required',
        'progressIndicator' => 'required',
        'body'  => 'required',
        'image' => 'image|max:1024|nullable'
    ]);


    $image_name = $this->image->getClientOriginalName();
    $this->image->storeAs('public/photos', $image_name);
    $project = new Project();
    $project->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $project->title = $this->title;
    
    $project->status = $this->status;
    $project->budget = $this->budget;
    $project->proposed_by = $this->proposedBy;
    $project->executed_by = $this->executedBy;
    $project->starting_date = Carbon::create($this->startingDate);
    $project->completion_date = Carbon::create($this->completionDate);
    $project->progress_indicator = $this->progressIndicator;
    $project->body = $this->body;
    $project->cover_image = $image_name;
    $project->save();


    foreach ($this->projectImages as $projectImage) {

             $image_name = $projectImage->getClientOriginalName();

            $projectImage->storeAs('public/photos', $image_name);
            
            foreach ($this->captions as $caption) {

                $projectImages = new ProjectImages();
                $projectImages->project_id = $project->id;
                $projectImages->images = $image_name;
                $projectImages->caption = $caption;
            
               $projectImages->save();
            }


    }
    
    $this->notification()->success(
        $title = 'Success',
        $description = 'Project Created Successfully'
    );
    $this->reset();
}
```

so just so you can see visually what am trying to do here is a screenshot of the form

[image: what the project form looks like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you only want each project image to have one caption. If that's the case then the nested foreach loops are unnecessary and changing it to one foreach like this should solve the problem.

```
foreach ($this->projectImages as $key => $value) {
        $image_name = $value->getClientOriginalName();
        $value->storeAs('public/photos', $image_name);
        $projectImages = new ProjectImages();
        $projectImages->project_id = $project->id;
        $projectImages->images = $image_name;
        $projectImages->caption = $this->captions[$key];
        $projectImages->save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you a million times @Stefano Christian Wiryana I am grateful.

Comment: Dou you think a nested loop is needed if we have more than one caption for each image?

Comment: You're welcome! And yes, if each image have more than one caption then nested loop is needed.